# How to solve this linear different moduli equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

In exercise $1.10$ in this book https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~kbelabas/teach/N1MA9W11/book.pdf it says we can solve

$$(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\Bbb Z^n\mbox{ such that }\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\dots&a_{mn}}\pmatrix{x_{1}\\\vdots\\
x_{n}}=\pmatrix{b_{1}\bmod M_{1}\\\vdots\\b_{m}\bmod M_{m}}$$

1. Can someone please explain how?
2. Can we solve if $a_{1i}=a_{2i}=\dots=a_{mi}$ at every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @Wuestenfux sure can you give the linear algebraic procedure at $m=n,m<n, m>n$?